# 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing when requesting access to storage using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-permissions

I am trying to get permission to access music files in android using onAudioQuery package flutter but it is giving me this error:

```
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\on_audio_query-2.6.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\lucasjosino\on_audio_query\OnAudioQueryPlugin.kt: (38, 1): Class 'OnAudioQueryPlugin' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onRequestPermissionsResult(p0: Int, p1: Array<(out) String!>, p2: IntArray): Boolean defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener
e: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\on_audio_query-2.6.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\lucasjosino\on_audio_query\OnAudioQueryPlugin.kt: (148, 5): 'onRequestPermissionsResult' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

And My code is here:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final OnAudioQuery _audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();
  bool permissionStatus = false;
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    permissionStatus = await _audioQuery.permissionsStatus();
    if (!permissionStatus) {
      permissionStatus = await _audioQuery.permissionsRequest();
    }
  }
  runApp(
    ProviderScope(
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: ThemeMode.dark,
        darkTheme: MyTheme.themeData,
        home:
            permissionStatus == true ? const SplashScreen() : const ErrorPage(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Flutter 3 and unfortunately on_audio_query 2.6 is not compatible with Flutter 3

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the `on_audio_query` plugin and now it supports `Flutter 3`.

Update to:

```yaml
dependencies:
  on_audio_query: ^2.6.1
```

See on [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/on_audio_query/versions/2.6.1)